# Finding words *in any order* within a line in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

wondering if there is a way to do a global search in a Visual Studio project (VS2010, if it matters) for all lines that contain word1, word2, and word3, arranged in any order?

Comment: You could use a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for the note. Regular expreessions can work, but to my understanding are a real pain to implement when the ordering of the three words needs to be allowed to be arbitrary... (especially when forced to use Visual Studio 2010's bastardized version of regular expressions - see accepted answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said VS2010, but for the benefit of anyone searching in the future, in VS versions after 2010, you can do this which is much better.  For VS2010 and below, see the second option.

Given word1, word2 and word3

Use Edit --> Find in files.
Check the Use Regular Expressions option.

Enter this as the search term:

```
^(?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b)(?=.*\bword3\b).+
```

Should do what you want.  For reference this is a [positive lookahead.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

As Michael correctly points out, this does not work in VS2010 or earlier.  For that I revert to a very clunky solution that is almost too embarrassing to post {cringe}:

```
.*(word1|word2|word3).*(word1|word2|word3).*(word1|word2|word3).*
```

This obviously does not scale well and will also match word1 word1 word1, etc. but it will narrow down the results for you at least.  If you want to find whole words only, add `\b` to the beginning and end of each word.

Comment: Unfortunately, Visual Studio 2010 and earlier don't support this syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, user3525898.  The fact that the first, simpler version of the query works on VS2012 and VS2013 is another reason for me to bite the bullet and upgrade from VS2010 to VS2013.